# Update query to convert existing complex json object to array using SQL

Tags: mysql, rdbms, mysql-json

I have a table that contains a JSON column. Currently, the JSON column holds data which has the below schema :

Input or Source JSON looks like below :

```
    "Q1": {
        "id": 1,
        "value": 12
    },
    "Q2": [{
        "id": 1,
        "value": 12
    }, {
        "id": 1,
        "value": 12
    }],
    "Q3": {
        "id": 1,
        "additional": true
    }
}
```

I have to perform a migration activity wherein I need to convert the **Q1 key's** value type from **JSON object to JSON array**. I don't see any utility functions which can help me in MySQL. Please suggest a suitable approach that can help me.

Result JSON should look like below

```
{
    "Q1": [{
        "id": 1,
        "value": 12
    }],
    "Q2": [{
        "id": 1,
        "value": 12
    }, {
        "id": 1,
        "value": 12
    }],
    "Q3": {
        "id": 1,
        "additional": true
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a result sample of what you needed.

Comment: @IbrahimHammed I have edited my question with Input JSON and Output JSON .